# How to disallow people saving the source code of my site?

Tags: javascript, html, http, dom, save-as

I know it's impossible. The browser has downloaded all the source codes once it showed it. But if you go to this site using Chrome:

http://www.myfreshnet.com/BIG5/literature/plugin/indextext.asp?free=100199307&bookid=100002750

and press `Ctrl+S` to save the page, nothing inside the `<body>` tag is saved!

How do they achieve this?

Comment: I never do this but you can try it.  Add a key event on you dom and do preventdefault inside your event code

Comment: Thats is the source of the webpage. If you inspect elemnt and save all the elements from `developers console` then you can access that web page too. There is no way you can prevent this.

Comment: just obfuscate your code if you think it's so precious someone would want to steal it. That will allow a couple more guys to earn a living writing the 1.000.000th acordion menu and the 1.000.000.000th spinning wheel.

Comment: If you disable Javascript or use Chrome dev tools (or other) , you will be able to save the source code.

Comment: @Weby, I just tried to disable JavaScript but still I cannot save the <body> part of the sourcde code. So it's not related to JS...

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible - how to get the source in a few easy steps:

1. In Chrome, right-click on the page and select inspect element.
2. Now go to the "elements" tab.
3. Now Traverse the hierarchy until the root `html` element.
4. Now right-click that element and click "copy".

You now have the entire webpage source in your clipboard.

There is no way to ask a browser to render your page while hiding it at the same time.

Comment: Question is about disallowing user, not about how to access it !

Comment: I know. But a regular Internet user may not know this. While some of them may try to save it as html or txt.

Comment: @user2335065, In that case you have few things to be handled like prevent `F12` key, disable `right click` etc...

Answer (score 1):

This page has one big frame element, and inside this frame element it loads page from another url. And still you can see source code of the iframe for example in network tab in chrome developer tools (F12).